# Set a server variable with mod_rewrite, as well as redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file that does multiple re-write commands and works well. However, while testing it, I left out one critical piece of information, setting the id in the $_SERVER variables (I'm using $_SERVER in my php script).

I have a URL example.com/f/847f34c76f64cad96effc8e9c3cea176 where the long string represents an id and f stands for the script to handle the request.

I have the following rewrite, which handles the script part.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/f/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /scriptf.php [L]
```

Like I said, this handles the redirect correctly. But, I also need the id placed in an environment variable. Something like this is what I was thinking

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/f/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=id:$1]
RewriteRule ^ /scriptf.php [L]
```

but sadly this does not work.

**Also, sending the id in a query is not a valid solution for my case.**

**EDIT**: error log output for reference:

```
[Tue Oct 08 10:48:31 2013] [error] [client 192.168.77.53] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: It looks like you are on the right track, but you need to use `%1` rather than `$1` in your env line, because you matched it from `RewriteCond`.

Comment: I did change it to %1, and still getting a 500 error

Comment: Look in your error log. There you'll find what the 500 error actually is.

Comment: Ah, it's because your RewriteConds only apply to the first `RewriteRule`.  You can place the `[E=id:%1]` in the same `RewriteRule` that points to `scriptf.php` as `[L,E=id:%1]` should work, I think.

Comment: That seems to work, created a variable called REDIRECT_id. Any way I can change that to be just id? or is that just the way it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `id` to be available in `$_GET['id']`, change your code to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^f/(.+)$ /scriptf.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

OR else If you want `id` to be available in `$_SERVER` array, change your code to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^f/(.+)$ /scriptf.php [L,NC,E=ID:$1]
```

Then you can use following variable inside PHP:

```
$_SERVER["REDIRECT_ID"]
```

Comment: "_Also, sending the id in a query is not a valid solution for my case._"

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: But didn't OP write: `I left out one critical piece of information, setting the id in the $_SERVER variables`

Comment: I have also provided an alternate rule to make `id` available as PATH_INFO (in case that suits OP better)

Comment: I need something like $_SERVER["id"] = 847f34c76f64cad96effc8e9c3cea176

Comment: @ScottJoudry: check the edited answer. That id will be available as `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_ID"]`

Comment: This is working for me now, any way to get $_SERVER["id"] rather than $_SERVER["REDIRECT_id"]?

Comment: @ScottJoudry: Unfortunately that prefix is added by mod_rewrite for every successful rewrite. So if a URI is rewritten twice you might get  `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_REDIRECT_ID"]`